# Dual apps in Android launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-package-managers, dual-sim

I'm creating an Android launcher. Some users have dual apps set up, e.g. for work (like WhatsApp with a dual sim). **Now, I want to display both the default and dual instance of these apps**, but only the default instance is showing (which makes sense given that I store all apps in a HashMap by their packageNames and the packageName is unique per app). I've tried searching for a solution to find the dual instance of an app, but came up empty.

I'm querying for packages through the `PackageManager`'s [queryIntentActivities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)):

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> allActivities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

Then I retrieve the packageName from the `ResolveInfo` of all activities and add it to the list of apps, if it wasn't in there already. How can I find out whether an app has a second instance which should be displayed in the launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this dual app feature is currently not supported for third-party launchers.

A solution we're proposing to users is to download an app like [Dual Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.hider.master.dual.app), [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl) or any other app that helps with accessing dual accounts from a different SIM.

Hopefully in the future, third party launchers will also be able to use this dual app feature by themselves.